# A square FrameworkElement in XAML fitting/filling its parent for Windows Store 8 or Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, multibinding

I'd like to have a FrameworkElement in XAML with equal Width and Height, fitting (or filling) its parent, without hardcoding Width and Height to specific values, for both Windows Store 8 and Windows Phone 8 (not necessarily the same solution).

For the purpose of this example, I'll use an `<Image/>`, but it could be any FrameworkElement.

I've attempted the following, which will make a FrameworkElement square based on parent's Width. But I wasn't able to make it square based on the "minimal" (or maximal) value between parent's Height and Width.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image
        Height="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=OneWay}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        />
</Grid>
```

I've attempted the following, but it is said to only *scale* and doesn't actually *size* the FrameworkElement. Height and Width will still be "1":

```
<ViewBox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Image
        Height="1"
        Width="1"
        />
</ViewBox>
```

I've heard about `<MultiBinding/>` (for Windows Store 8 only, not Windows Phone 8 sadly), but wasn't able to code the *square* behavior.

Comment: Its a little hard to understand what you're trying to do.  I think you mean you want to maintain aspect ratio as it stretches?  You can use a viewbox for this.  Your choices are [Fill](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Weoup.png), [Uniform](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iqVJu.png), and [UniformToFill](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xT9ma.png)